# Atmosphere Colour Change (Blender Render)

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, light

Just a quick congrats to the moderators who won! Glad to see some friendly faces keeping their spots as you've help so many out including me with this project and others.

Back to my Earth project. Done some more tweaking and have much more to do to try and perfect everything. My next step though is changing the colour of the atmosphere when transitioning from day to night. I want to have that golden/orange glow that appears around the edges of the day and night shift. I've attached my current render and what I'd like the transition to eventually look like.

My render:
[image]

What I'm aiming for:
[image]

I'm also trying to make 3D clouds as well or 3D manipulated clouds with the texture I'm currently using. But one at a time ey? Look forward to hearing your suggestions!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7509/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18393/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8847/599

Comment: @gandalf3 This isn't with the Cycles engine just the normal Blender Render. I've now changed the title addressing this.