# Cycles: "Image as plane" show shadow from other objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have an image which has been added by Images as a plane. Now if I create a cube above the plane I want the shadow of the cube to be visible on the texture. How to do this?

Update: this is my plane in nodes view now:

[image]

Comment: In cycles all of the objects cast and receive shadows by default, there is nothing to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions. Option 1 is easier and better.

### Option 1 (Diffuse)

When importing the the image, make sure that you have *Diffuse* selected under *Material Settings* on the left side.

[image]

### Option 2 (Emission)

I have searched far and wide for a solution to test for a shadow so that one can use the *Emission* setting with some extra nodes, but eventually concluded that it cannot be done. The final word came from gandalf3's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8255/can-the-areas-of-an-object-in-shadow-be-accessed-in-cycles?rq=1). You can, however, do a workaround through *RenderLayers*, if you so desire.

*Final result:*

[image]

*Nodes:*

[image]

What I have setup are two *RenderLayers*. One with the cube and image (Scene), and one with a plane with identical dimensions to the image with a plain *Diffuse BSDF* material (Shadow). I also enabled *Transparent* under *Properties panel > Render tab > Film drop down*.

This is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: for Option 1. If I go to Material tab (image is already imported as plane).
I go to "Surface" and see: Surface=emission, Color:Image Texture, Strength: 1. 

but if I change Surface=emission to Diffuse BSDF, my text object doesn't drop any shadow.

any ideas?

Comment: @juFo There could still be a light path node in your node tree. I will say that the option that I have a picture of is visible in the file browser only when you are selecting which image to import. If this doesn't help, please consider posting screenshots. Also, if this or my answer helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: see my updated screenshot.

Comment: @juFo on its own, that node set up should receive a shadow. I can think of a couple other things that might be the cause. Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)? Before you do upload it, you should go to _File > External Data_ and check _Automatically Pack Into .blend_.

Comment: I'm using images I can't share. I'll have a look at it on Monday (got to go to a meeting now). I'll try to have a look in between this weekend.

Comment: @juFo OK. You could also always substitute random images just for me to play around with.

Comment: Shady Puck, ok i've re-imported the image as plane with diffuse BSDF instead of emission and now it seems to works. To increase the shadow effect I've also added a second lamp with higher strength. Thanks!

Comment: @juFo If my answer helped, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark in the upper-left hand corner of my answer. It would help me greatly and make me very happy!