# How do you use an image in a blender animation?

Tags: texturing, materials, image

I'm making a video intro and I would like to use a logo (.png image) in the animation.

I tried using an *Image Empty* but I've learned that they don't render.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

## Import Images as Planes Add-on

This is an add-on bundled with Blender. Go to *File > User Preferences > Addons* and type **Import Images as Planes**. Check the add-on to enable it.

[image]

### Cycles Render

Key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select *Mesh > Images as Planes*. Find the image in the *File Browser*. On the lefthand side, choose either *Diffuse* or *Emission* considering that *Emission* does not require a light source but does not receive shadows (without a crazy amount of *Compositing*; see my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56996/cycles-image-as-plane-show-shadow-from-other-objects)) and *Diffuse* does require a light source and, likewise, receives shadows. Click *Import Images as Planes*.

[image]

### Blender Render

Key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select *Mesh > Images as Planes*. Find the image in the *File Browser*. On the lefthand side, either check *Shadeless* or don't considering that *Shadeless* does not require a light source but does not receive shadows and not checking *Shadeless* does require a light source and, likewise, receives shadows. Click *Import Images as Planes*.

[image]