# Is it possible to have a Material input node in the Cycles Renderer?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

The Blender Render(er) has the so called "Material Input Node", where a previously defined material can be selected. The questions is, whether there is an equavalent for the Cycles Render(er).

Comment: No. However you can do something sortof like this with renderlayers, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2612/599

Comment: What would you use it for? Node groups can help both in linking materials or creating an interface where you can plug in maps...

Comment: It may help you to note that Mix Shaders and Add Shaders are the two types of nodes that can actually combine other shaders. So if what you're trying to combine can't be handled by one of those two combination methods then you need to tackle it at the color level, using MixRGB nodes and such.

Comment: I think the [ubershader](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/03/04/ubershader-material/) would be the closest to the old material node.

Comment: @Carlo In BI you can use the *result* of one material in the nodes of another material, which allows you to do things like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/701/599).

Comment: Thanks for the link @gandalf3. I never thought of that usage: BI will always have its say! I'm with you, a perfect equivalent cannot exist. Were you (the questioner) looking for getting the material *result*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the given answers in the comments work correctly and as I expected.

I finally ended up using the `Node Groups`.