# How do you affect only shaded areas in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, normals, shadows

I am trying to make a pyramid shaped planet, and want to make the shadowed areas use a different texture (with city lights) than the areas in the light.  I have tried using the normals node, but it doesn't rotate with the planet.

[image]

Here's the nodes that I have right now, with the normal node creating the shadow.  However, when I rotate the pyramid, the "shadow" moves with the object instead of staying opposite the light.

This isn't a very important animation, so any workaround or solution would be appreciated, given that it's fairly simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?319291-Different-Materials-for-Light-and-Shadow-Side-of-an-Object-(Cycles)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check this out.  It looks like exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No, this is fundamentally impossible to achieve in Cycles, a material property can never depend on the rendered result. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/make-light-paths-only-pass-through-non-emitted-areas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make light paths only pass through non-emitted areas?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/make-light-paths-only-pass-through-non-emitted-areas)

Comment: @Duarte Farrojota Ramos https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/earth-cycles#comment-2523653071

Comment: That is not being affected by shaded areas, that is being manually controlled by normals. If you change the lamp position the solution will be wrong until you adjust normals again, as expected.

Comment: But when rotate the planet/object, it does change the shadow, which is what I wanted.  Luckily for me, I didn't need to move the light.  I do understand what you are saying, though, and I hope blender adds some sort of way to do that in the future :)