# How to put one material where the light is hitting and one where the light isn't?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, light

So I want to create an object using cycles render that has two different materials applied to it. One of the materials can only be seen on the object where the light is hitting and the other material can only be seen where the light isn't hitting. And of course these two materials should blend between the shadow and light.  Let's just say I want the shadow part to be glossy and the light part to be diffuse.How would the nodes look like?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make light paths only pass through non-emitted areas?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/make-light-paths-only-pass-through-non-emitted-areas)

Comment: Well that post doesn't have anything helpful.

Comment: Are you sure, have you read my answer? Cycles materials can't depend on the render solution, that creates an endless dependency cycle

Comment: If your input is a single point lamp, we could implement it using some simple math. Other than this, Duarte gave you the answer.

Comment: You can do it in Blender Internal .. you can do it in Cycles in 2 passes, (baking the first) ... you  will be able to do it in Eevee.