# How to make a part of a textured object go 'untextured' whenever that certain part is cast by shadow?

Tags: texturing, lighting

I'm trying to make an object wherein it has a textured part that goes untextured when that part is shadowed.

Image example of the effect that I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/make-light-paths-only-pass-through-non-emitted-areas/86787#86787