How to permanently change the color after the light hits the animation?
I'm new to blender, so I need some advice. I would like to create a shader that permanently changes color when a beam of light hits it. I have created an animation where the object is rotating and the spotlights are static and I would like to change the color wherever the spotlight rays hit.
Thanks for your help.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86787/19307
