# City lights on a planet

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Argh guys I need some help
I've made an alien world, got the lighting set up and I don't know how to the night lighting on the dark side of the planet. Does any know if there's a way to detect edges between one colour or another and apply a different material to it?
I'd use an earth map but the continents are not the same so it looks bad.
I don't think an image is going to help so...
Thanks

Comment: even i had a doubt like this and i got a solution in youtube. i included the link down below https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hvx4pYGK0a0 hope this helps you
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/how-can-i-mix-two-materials-based-on-incoming-light

Comment: also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/701/brightness-dependent-texture-on-mesh/703#703